# Anaconda errors in Terminal and VS Code

Tags: python, macos, anaconda

Running into an issue I'm not sure how to resolve:
Installed VS Code, and used Homebrew to install Python 3.7, then installed Anaconda - was given an option to install it to my user home, and chose that option.

When I start up Terminal or VS Code though, I'm hitting this error - what have I likely missed?

```
Last login: Sat Dec 22 22:04:18 on ttys000
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/<myusername>/anaconda2/bin/conda", line 7, in <module>
    from conda.cli import main
ImportError: No module named conda.cli
```

(Mac running Sierra)

I've attempted the following:

```
export PYTHONPATH="$HOME/.miniconda2/lib/python2.7:$HOME/.miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH"
```

and the paths do appear to include Anaconda's paths. Python indicates Anaconda is present as well:

```
Python 3.7.1 (default, Dec 14 2018, 13:28:58) 
[Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

I'm sure I've missed a detail somewhere, but not sure what.

Comment: please type "which python" and let us know the result and include it in a comment.

Comment: Hi jmh 21, thanks for getting back to me.
Here's the requested output:

My-MacBook-Pro:~ <myusername>$ which python
/Users/<myusername>/anaconda3/bin/python

Comment: The disparity between anaconda2 in the error output and anaconda3 in the which python output seems like a likely culprit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Likely this was a brute-force solution, but running anaconda-clean and then uninstalling anaconda2 and anaconda3, and finally reinstalling anaconda3 appears to have resolved this, since I don't actually need anaconda on Python2.7. I imagine the correct solution if I needed them both would be to set up additional environments to handle this.